# save multiple hidden fields in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have two hidden that the user is not able to fill from form, but I want to provide values for these fields before I save the entry.

I have the snippet below to achieve this if I have just one hidden field, but not sure how to make it work for more than one.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    var1 = AppName(col1=value1)
    # var2 = Notice(col2=value2)
    form = AppNameForm(request.POST, instance=var1)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("home")
```

How can I bring `var2` into the form values before saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating an object of `AppName` then assign each hidden attribute of the class the values I want, then pass the object to the `instance` option.

```
app_obj = AppName()
app_obj.col1 = val1
app_obj.col2 = val2
form = AppNameForm(request.POST, instance=app_obj)
```